# Deploy Angular 7 Server Git

Tags: angular-6

gostaria de poder mandar um deploy em Angular 7 para um servidor DigitalOcean, através dos comandos git

A arquitetura do meu projeto está organizado desta maneira (pastas)

```
Meu-projeto
  .git
  dist
     deploy-meu-projeto
  e2e
  node_modules
  src
  ...
```

Eu gostaria de mandar para o servidor, apenas o deploy de meu projeto, apenas a produção, através do comando git

Comment: Já utilizou Git antes? Sabe como ele funciona?

Comment: sim, sim, gostaria de executar o comando "git push -u origin master", mas que ele subisse apenas a produção, não todo o projeto, entendeu ?